# UINavigationController corruption on iPad+Master Detail + TabBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, master-detail, corruption, ipad

I have this annoying problem, and have searched far and wide. I think there are too many related terms that cloud my searches. So here goes:

I have a master-detail application on iPad. The master view controller is a tab bar controller. Each tab is a navigation controller which in place holds the relevant root controller. Like so:
[image: Storyboard representation of my project]

Problem is that when I push another controller on one the tabbed navigation controllers, the navigation stack becomes messed up. The navigation bar updates, but the actual content or controller doesn't. If I play enough with it, it also crashes with an *"Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions"*

The problem only happens when the iPad starts at portrait mode. If it starts in landscape, everything works as should. Sometimes alternating between the two will fix it, and sometimes will lead to the unbalanced crash.

Hope I listed enough information for help, I can't pinpoint the exact problem which makes this question a bit hard to ask.

**Edit:**

I'm pushing the view controller like so:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"pushMyControllerSegue" sender: self];
```

*pushMyControllerSegue* is defined as *style=push* and *destination=current*

And for what's its worth, this is my *prepareForSegue*:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushMyControllerSegue"]) {
        MyController *myController = segue.destinationViewController;
        myController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you pushing (where is it, show the code)?

Comment: in addition to the push in the segue, are you using push with a button as well.? if so remove that because the this type of errors happens most of time when two push calls are being called. generally speaking the errors related to two view controllers being pushed at the same time or two methods trying to push the same view at the same time. also check the segue in the story board as well.

Comment: Didn't have any duplicate push's. Re-installed the relevant segue's and still no good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, solved it eventually with a "band aid" - i.e. didn't find the root cause, but hacked a bit to make it work.

From debugging *a lot* I'm fairly certain it has to do with the Master disappearance in portrait mode. As I mentioned before, switching to a different tab and returning to the original one solves the problem. So I tried doing this programatically. If I open the master before the tab controller switches back to the original tab - it solves the problem. If I open it *after* it switched back the problem is still there.

(To switch back I used `performSelector:withDelay`, thus making sure switching the tabs back and forth actually switched tabs and was not canceled by internal optimization of the tab bar controller. It also allowed me to play with when the switching is done)

So what I did (if this helps anyone) - On the following delegate method

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc popoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc willPresentViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
```

I switched away from and back to the selected tab. No `performSelector:withDelay` was necessary.

Maybe a bug on Apple's side - not sure... In any case I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some issue with your segues in storyboard. Give identifiers to your view controllers in storyboard and try using the following code instead of segues to push a view controller:

```
MyController *vc= (MyController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"YOUR_VIEWCONTROLLER_IDENTFIER"];
vc.delegate=self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```